# Are the angles in a halved circle right?

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

Imagine a circle cut in half. Now, are the two angles on it right? I can imagine when going limitedly close that they would be.

Got curious about this question after seeing [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d17iS.png) on the internet.

Comment: Rather strange that this is being asked almost right after this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041758/does-a-semicircle-have-2-right-angles/4041795?r=SearchResults#4041795 Has this just gone viral or something? I didn't vote to close this as a duplicate as it already has answers and, more importantly, the question is posed slightly differently.

Comment: Maybe :D Sadly, I do not know the original source of the picture, I got it from a friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends upon how you define angle. But if you define the angle between two intersecting curves at a point $P$ at which they intersect as the angle between their tangent lines at $P$ (which is a reasonable definition) then, yes, there are two right angles in that picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the angle between two vectors $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$ as
$$
\arccos\left(\frac{\bf{x \cdot y}}{\bf{|x||y|}}\right) \, ,
$$
and the angle between two intersecting curves as the angle between their tangent lines, then the angle pictured in the diagram is a right angle:

[image: Intersection of two curves]

To prove this, take any two vectors that act along the tangent lines, for instance $u=-\mathbf{i}$ and $v=\mathbf{j}$. Then,
$$
\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
= 0
$$
and $\arccos(0)=\pi/2$. This approach to defining what an angle is requires you to define $\cos$ and $\arccos$ analytically, as otherwise the definition would be circular.